# Migrating to Japanese Language & Usage

Tags: feature-request, moderation

Questions about language and expressions are bound to happen over and over. Another [meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69/should-we-allow-questions-that-are-about-japanese-language-use-in-anime-manga) makes a point that they sometimes belong here (character-centric) and sometimes, to [JLU](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/) for being generic or not specific to anime.

It is hard for a non-Japanese to know this a'priori, so, we shouldn't penalize (by closing) questions that are a better fit at JLU simply because the author would first need to know the answer to know they are a better fit there. Instead, migrating them once it's been established they are a better fit there should be completely natural reaction.

If the migration path is not yet available, adding a request to admins to create it.

Comment: In addition to JLU, Arqade is also a good candidate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Migration paths are added for non-mod users, for sites where the flow is "constant" and not occasional. Moderators can migrate to any site in any moment, so the absence of migration paths is not a problem.

Until you get a migration path, the course of action that I suggest is:

- **Vote to close** and/or
- **flag**, choose **custom** and write something like

> Off topic, please migrate to [site]
>   
>   Be concise. :P In any case, don't do the second while we're still in Beta. Your flag might be declined.

Ah one last thing: Meta is (and will be) always the first option for migrating. :) So you're going to have a maximum of 4 extra sites in general, I think.

Comment: You're not in private beta anymore...

Comment: @casperOne We still cannot migrate unless we flag, no?

Comment: You don't have enough 2K users yet, so moderator attention is currently the only way.

Answer (score 3):

Some notes about how this will play out once we go further. Alenanno notes what's relevant for us at the moment since we're in private beta - no migration, period.

Once we enter public beta, the main method to migrate will be to flag a post for moderator attention. Then, someone on the community team, or your pro tem moderator team when that shows up, will handle the rest. In this vein, any kind of migration is fine if it works, we don't need concrete paths.

If this site reaches graduation, then we can open official migration paths that even normal users will be able to use when voting to close. However, the requirements to this are strict. We need a **demonstrated need of the migration path as illustrated by a history of migration**. That is, we don't just add a migration path based on logical connection. Consider Arqade, our Gaming site, and our Game Development site. In logic, they would make sense to migrate to each other. In practice, there is no history of migration from Game Dev over to Arqade, and there have been only less than 30 questions migrated from Arqade to Game Dev over the course of over 2 years. So there isn't enough "wrong traffic" to warrant the official public path to be established, it's unnecessary.

Let's wait and see what migration trends we see as the coming months go by, then we can revisit this topic.